# Calculate Average using XSLT XPath plus ascending order

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying trying to get an average using XPath but I get NaN as the output.

Here's my XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="class.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<university>
<student><sname>Charlie Parker</name>
<course sigle="INF8430" note="69" />
<course sigle="INF1030" note="65" />
<course sigle="INF1230" note="73" /></student>
<student><name>Miles Davis</name>
<course sigle="INF8430" note="65" />
<course sigle="INF1030" note="77" />
<course sigle="INF1230" note="83" /></student>
<student><name>John Coltrane</name>
<course sigle="INF9430" note="24" />
<course sigle="INF1030" note="64" />
<course sigle="INF1230" note="56" /></student>
<student><name>Charles Mingus</name>
<course sigle="INF8430" note="34" />
<course sigle="INF1230" note="89" /></student>
</university>
```

Now the XSL file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="university">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Average</th>
</tr>
<xsl:for-each select="student">
<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="sum(.//student/@note) div count(.//    student/@note)"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Another problem I have is when I try to sort the last names by ascending order in the table. It just won' work.

I've tryed to add this bit of code without success :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="student" >
<xsl:sort select="substring-after(name,' ')" order="ascending"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

Can you guys help me sorting that out?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/university">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Average</th>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="student">
                    <xsl:sort select="substring-after(name, ' ')"/>
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(course/@note) div count(course)"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! One last thing, what should I do if I want to round the average at 1 decimal number? Thanks again!

Comment: I've tryed to add format-number round to count(course) but I get an error.

Comment: You want to round the average, not the count (which will always be an integer). Use:  `<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(course/@note) div count(course), '0.#')"/>`.

Comment: I just tryed your code but I get NaN as average results.